# How to pass Arguments between build configuration steps in team city?

Tags: arguments, teamcity

I am new to team city and i just started using the existing team city configuration.  I have a requirement to pass the build number (ex:- 7.6.0.4) generated in a build configuration (01 Build Services Installer) to another build configuration (03 deploy installers).  The Build number is generated at run time so it will change for every build.  How can i pass this build number to the one of the build step in 'deploy installers' configuration?  I am using powershell to run my script and i need to pass this build number to this powershell script.

Thanks in advance.

[Team City Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTjr3.jpg)

Answer (score 8):

The regular way to achive this in TeamCity would be to define a Dependency between the builds, then you can access all Parameters from previous builds.

1. Define a Snapshot dependency between "Build Services Installers" and "Deploy Installers" (if not already done)
2. You can now access all Parameters of the first build in "Deploy Installers" by typing %dep. - Autocomplete will tell you the rest.

Comment: Mecaveli, thanks for your suggestion.  It worked well.  I have added the Snapshot dependency onto "Build Services Installers" and could use %dep.....% parameter to extract the latest build number from it.  I never know that we can get the parameters using Snapshot dependency.  Good Learning.  Thanks a ton for your help.

Comment: You´re welcome, feel free to upvote / accept my answers if it was helpful :)