# How to run the same build with different predefined parameters in TeamCity

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, build-process

I try to improve our build process and use 2-3 predefined parameters for run on one single build.

**Description:** we have build configuration with parameters C1, C2, C3 and related build steps B1, B2, B3. They link to each other C1-B1, C2-B2, C3-B3. In this scheme all works fine, I pass parameters like mentioned here - [How to pass Arguments between build configuration steps in team city?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869384/how-to-pass-arguments-between-build-configuration-steps-in-team-city),

but I'm a bit worried because B1, B2, B3 are full copy each other and this i would like to improve it. Only one problem I couldn't find any mechanism to pass parameters from different configuration.If I use `%dep.` mechanism i can use parameter from only one configuration.

**UPD**: Currect scheme

```
+---+   +---+   +---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
| C1|   | C2|   | C3|
|   |   |   |   |   |
+-+-+   +-+-+   +-+-+
  |       |       |
  |       |       |
+-v-+   +-v-+   +-v-+
|   |   |   |   |   |
| B1|   | B2|   | B3|
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+   +---+   +---+
```

the desired scheme:

```
+---+   +---+   +---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
| C1|   | C2|   | C3|
|   |   |   |   |   |
+-+-+   +-+-+   +-+-+
  |       |       |
  |       |       |
  |     +-v--+    |
  |     |    |    |
  |     |    |    |
  +-----> B1 <----+
        |    |
        +----+
```

C1, C2, C3 setup configuration parameters
B1 contains only build steps, like `clean, build, dist`

Could anyone help me with that? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you can introduce a TeamCity Metarunner. The idea is that you combine multiple build steps with parameters, and extract them as new entity, available as build runner.

See this [documentation section](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Working+with+Meta-Runner#WorkingwithMeta-Runner-CreatingYourOwnMeta-RunnerfromUI) for step by step instructions on creating a metarunner.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a parameter in the template, call it, for example, `external.param` and give no definition.

Then, in each configuration (C1, C2 and C3) define the value of this parameter as reference to specific dependency.

```
external.param = %dep.<source_cfg_id>.<source_param_name>%
```

Comment: how should i define external.param in B1? if i define like you suggested external.param would link it only on one configuration

Comment: in all build steps (B1, B2 and B3) you would refer to same `external.param`. Then, in each of configurations C1, C2 and C3 set the value of `external.param` to specific dependency.

Comment: ok, I see. This is what i do now, but i try to remove B1, B2, B3 and use only one B1, because B1, B2, B2 are just copies

Comment: So, how did it go for you?

Comment: sorry, but this is not what i'm looking for. I'm looking for a way to reduce amount of copies. But If i understand teamcity ideology right, this way doesn't exist. I should just copy build configurations. PS. Edit main post

Comment: thanks for update. The way does exist actually. I will add another answer soon